# regex in Java -- only last match is returned

Tags: java, regex, string

The snippet below should return and store matches in the ArrayList but for some reason, I get only the last match, that is `23`; I would expect `256` and `23` of course. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

String target = "nawaK256he23llo";
String regexNb = "[0-9]+";

Pattern patternNb = Pattern.compile(regexNb);
Matcher mNb = patternNb.matcher(target);

List<String> allMatchesNb = new ArrayList<String>();

while (mNb.find()) {
   System.out.println("mNb matched : " + mNb.find());
   allMatchesNb.add(mNb.group());
   for (String nb : allMatchesNb) {
      System.out.println("content of ArrayList :" + nb);
   }      
}

}
```

Output is the following :

```
content of ArrayList : 23
```

Comment: Your loop calls `find()` twice at each iteration, once in `while` and once in `println`. Get rid of the second call .

Comment: Yes I've overlooked that, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid this problem, and don't change the logic of your code, you can use :

```
boolean find = false;//create a variable so you can use in the loo^p
while (find = mNb.find()) {
//          ^-------------------Initialize the variable
    System.out.println("mNb matched : " + find);
//------------------------------------------^^
```

**Note**

> It should be **one equal =** in `find = mNb.find()` not two, this is not a
>   condition it is an initialization, so you can use it in
>   `System.out.println("mNb matched : " + find);`

Answer (score 3):

you are calling [find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) twice and that is consuming the 1st match

```
System.out.println("mNb matched : " + mNb.find());
```

do instead:

```
String target = "nawaK256he23llo";
String regexNb = "[0-9]+";

Pattern patternNb = Pattern.compile(regexNb);
Matcher mNb = patternNb.matcher(target);

List<String> allMatchesNb = new ArrayList<>();

while (mNb.find()) {
    allMatchesNb.add(mNb.group());
}
System.out.println(allMatchesNb);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc of [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) (emphasis by me):

> Attempts to find the **next** subsequence of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or,
>   **if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched
>   by the previous match**.

You are calling `mNb.find()` twice in each iteration, the first one finds "256", the second one "23". The easiest solution would be to get rid of one invocation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String target = "nawaK256he23llo";
    String regexNb = "[0-9]+";

    Pattern patternNb = Pattern.compile(regexNb);
    Matcher mNb = patternNb.matcher(target);

    List<String> allMatchesNb = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (mNb.find()) {
        System.out.println("mNb matched : " + true);
        allMatchesNb.add(mNb.group());
        for (String nb : allMatchesNb) {
            System.out.println("content of ArrayList :" + nb);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
mNb matched : true
content of ArrayList :256
mNb matched : true
content of ArrayList :256
content of ArrayList :23
```